# Why is CORS header not respected as part of an XHR call?

Tags: jquery, cors, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have this snippet that I could run from the console on any site with jQuery, and the request is canceled even before I see its headers.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"https://example.com/api",
    cache:false,
    global:false,
    crossDomain:true,
    data: {
        'whatever': 1234
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType:"json"
});
```

The usual "blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" is seen in the console. But when I load my API URL on its own in a new tab, I can see the proper headers are set:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

It's there when inspecting with the developer tools. However, when running that snippet from a page, the Network tab lists its status as "canceled" and for headers I only see "Provisional headers are shown" and nothing for the real headers.

The API server is WordPress-based, and I believe I'm setting the headers right. Tried both methods from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213988/wp-headers-vs-send-headers-when-to-use-each).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I had to drop `withCredentials` as it disallows wildcard origin. Also, the API URL was missing a trailing slash. When a request is made to WP, it 301 redirects to the URL with the trailing slash. However, the first page (where the request lands) doesn't have the headers.